# how to check when sql server was installed

Tags: sql-server

I do not have access to the machine but I want to find out when this sql server was installed?

I have Server View state access which means I can access dmvs but I cannot connect to the machine, I cannot find any DMV with this information.

Comment: That question does not seem to be about programming. Please check the other StackExchange communities to find one that is more suitable to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this information is held in any of the DMVs but a place I usually look for is the `sys.server_principals`. Look for the `SYSTEM` or `NETWORK SERVICE` logins, this will indicate you when this SQL Server was installed.

```
Select Create_Date 
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE name = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
  OR  name = N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
```

Comment: Thank you sir this date on my server looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

use [**`sys.server_principals`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx)

```
SELECT create_date,*
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE sid = 0x010100000000000512000000 -- sid of NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Referred from below article by Pinal Dave

[SQL SERVER – Retrieve SQL Server Installation Date Time](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/05/sql-server-retrieve-sql-server-installation-date-time/)

This article [How to find out the SQL Server installation date?](https://sqldbpool.com/2013/08/27/how-to-find-out-the-sql-server-installation-date/) has much more options

```
-- work with only English language installations
SELECT createdate AS 'SQL Server Installation Date'
FROM   sys.syslogins
WHERE  NAME = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

--neutral language 
SELECT createdate AS 'SQL Server Installation Date'
FROM   sys.syslogins
WHERE  sid = 0x010100000000000512000000

--Using sys.server_principals 
SELECT create_date as 'SQL Server Installation Date'
FROM sys.server_principals 
WHERE name='NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think using a human readable/remember able or writable where clause is an easier option :)  , your suggested method does the same but I think M.Ali's query is easier to remember. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @user7418787 - Updated my answer with another article it has different options